# Account's owner can edit unowned Contact even though Contact's OWD is private

Tags: sharing, contact

I have a doubt regarding Salesforce Sharing mechanism. First Let's understand the configuration for my org

- OWD for Account and Contact is private.
- No Custom object in the org.
- Two users (User A and User B) **with no role** having profile with minimum access(Read, Create, Edit) only on Account, Contact and Opportunity.
- **No Sharing rule** on on any object.
- No Apex Sharing
- No Manager Sharing
- **No Territory Setup**

**Question** :
User A created an Account and manually shared it with User B keeping Account Access as Read Only.

User B had used that account to create a new Related Contact.

**Problem** starts here,
In My Org, Contact's OWD is private and there is no role setup for any of the user. How User A is able to view and even edit that Contact's record that is owned by User B ?

Is there any new update came on Contact Sharing that will give the Account owner editable access on all related contact records even if OWD is private.

Comment: Are you talking about internal or external users (the latter with digital experience/community)?

Comment: Yes, Internal users.